# Greyed out Connection options in SSMS

Tags: ssms-2012

I've run into an instance where I created a new query window, right-clicked to connect to a server and found the following options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Come to find out the reason this happened was because I created the new query window from a multi-instanced registered server such as below:

[image]

Just make sure to create your new query window from a single instanced registered server.

Comment: Sadly, I have this problem with SSMS 18, but we have no registered servers at all, so that isn't the problem. In my case, if I leave SSMS open overnight, with connected windows, those windows will all be disconnected by the morning, and all connection options disabled. The only solution is to open a new query window, which works fine (until left connected overnight). This is quite annoying, since I might have 5 or 6 such open windows. Even if the server is set to disconnect after an inactive period, SSMS shouldn't then block any subsequent connection the user might want to make (or reconnect).